# Pseudo code for Blockwise Non Local Means noise reduction algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I have implemented a nice algorithm ("[Non Local Means](http://www.stanford.edu/~slansel/tutorial/Papers/Non-Local%20Means/Review%20of%20Image%20Denoising%20Algorithms%20with%20a%20New%20One.pdf)") for reducing noise in image.
It is based on it's [Matlab implementation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13176-non-local-means-filter/content/NLmeansfilter.m).

The problem with NLMeans is that the original algorithm is slow even on compiled languages like c/c++ and i am trying to run it using scripting language.

One of best solutions is to use improved [Blockwise NLMeans algorithm](http://www.hal.inserm.fr/docs/00/16/96/58/PDF/Coupe07c.pdf) which is ~60-80 times faster. The problem is that the paper which describes it is written in a complex mathematical language and it's really hard for me to understand an idea and program it
(yes, i didn't learn math at college).

That is why i am desperately looking for a pseudo code of this algorithm.

(modification of original Matlab implementation would be just perfect)

Comment: Matlab is probably one of the languages that is closest to the mathematical notation. I doubt you will find someone to translate for you, but I suggest you look up the symbols and you should find the matlab methods to be a very good match.

Comment: Relet, i am not asking to translate Matlab code. It's pretty straightforward. I just couldn't find any matlab implementation of Blockwise Nlmeans

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I admit, I was intrigued until I saw the result – 260+ seconds on a dual core, and that doesn't assume the overhead of a scripting language, and that's for the Optimized Block Non Local Means filter.

Let me break down the math for you – My idea of pseudo-code is writing in Ruby.

#### Non Local Means Filtering

Assume an image that's 200 x 100 pixels (20000 pixels total), which is a pretty tiny image. We're going to have to go through 20,000 pixels and evaluate each one on the weighted average of the other 19,999 pixels: [Sorry about the spacing, but the equation is interpreted as a link without it]

NL [v] (i) = ∑ w(i,j)v(j) [j ∈ I]

where 0 ≤ w(i,j) ≤ 1 and ∑<sub>j</sub> w(i,j) = 1

Understandably, this last part can be a little confusing, but this is really nothing more than a convolution filter the size of the whole image being applied to each pixel.

#### Blockwise Non Local Means Filtering

The blockwise implementation takes overlapping sets of voxels (volumetric pixels - the implementation you pointed us to is for 3D space). Presumably, taking a similar approach, you could apply this to 2D space, taking sets of overlapping pixels. Let's see if we can describe this...

NL [v] (i<sub>j<sub>k</sub></sub>) = 1/|A<sub>i</sub>|∑ w(i<sub>j<sub>k</sub></sub>, i)v(i)

Where A is a vector of the pixels to be estimated, and similar circumstances as above are applied.

[NB: I may be slightly off; It's been a few years since I did heavy image processing]

#### Algorithm

In all likelihood, we're talking about reducing complexity of the algorithm at a minimal cost to reduction quality. The larger the sample vector, the higher the quality as well as the higher the complexity. By overlapping then averaging the sample vectors from the image then applying that weighted average to each pixel we're looping through the image far fewer times.

- Loop through the image to collect the sample vectors and store their weighted average to an array.
- Apply each weighted average (a number between 0 and 1) to each pixel times the pixels value.

Pretty simple, but the processing time is going to be horrid with larger images.

#### Final Thoughts

You're going to have to make some tough decisions. If you're going to use a scripting language, you're already dealing with significant interpretive overhead. It's far from optimal to use a scripting language for heavy duty image processing. If you're not processing medical images, in all likelihood, there are far better algorithms to use with lesser O's.

Hope this is helpful... I'm not terribly good at making a point clearly and concisely, so if I can clarify anything, let me know.

Comment: Thank you stslavik. I have found a way to write blockwise nlmeans. It is still very slow, but i am optimizing the code. Hope i'll have some results within a day or two.

Comment: Regarding your words about types of images and the algorithm: i am not processing medical images, i am targeting regular color images. The reason why i've chosen this algorithm is that is one of the best and i could find some pseudo code for it. For example there are other very nice algorithms like DCT or BM3D (which is best) but it's hard to find some working examples. And other algorithms don't produce the result i am expecting.

Comment: The reason I ask is that usually that level of processing is reserved for medical. I had the pleasure of working for a company back around 2005 that did image processing for video, medical, and casino security. For video, the emphasis was on compression and speed; for medical, clarity; and for security both were essential. Image processing relies heavily on the hardware and scripting languages tend to be sandboxed from too deep of hardware access.

Comment: @Termos can you please tell where you found pseudo code..I am searching for it for the past 24 hours.